# while loop, asking user if he wants to repeat the program problem

Tags: python

So I have this while loop which asks user if he/she wants to repeat the program. All works good but I was trying it out and found out that after user repeats the program and when asked second time if he/she wants to repeat, I choose no. But the program still repeats although it prints that program is closing, how can I fix this?

edit: I've fixed it with changing break with return and adding return after main()

```
def main():
  endFlag = False
  while endFlag == False:        
    # your code here
    print_intro()
    mode, message=get_input()
    ui = str.upper(input("Would you like to repeat the program again? Y/N:  "))
    while True:
      if ui == "Y":
       print(" ")
       main()
      elif ui == 'N':
        endFlag = True
        print("Program is closing...")
        break
      else:
        print("wrong input, try again")
        ui = str.upper(input("Would you like to repeat the program again? Y/N:  "))
```

Comment: replace `break` with `return`

Comment: it didnt fix it

Comment: Substitute the line `main()` in your inner loop with  `break`.

Comment: thanks Mr.T it did help but i substituted with return

Answer (score 0):

This is because main() function is being called recursively & endFlag is a local variable.

So when you first put 'y' , then another main() is recursively called from the first main() function.

After you put 'n' which ends this second main() and return to the first main which still in a loop with endFlag (local variable) with value as false.

So, need to change,

Either
endFlag variable as global ( i.e. defined outside main function )

Or,

some program exit function in place of break

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you're doing recursion over here, i.e. you're calling method `main()` inside `main()` and trying to break out of it the way you've done is not gonna work (well, you're know it :) )
Second - you don't need a forever loop inside a first loop, you can do it with one simple loop and break.
Here it is:

```
def print_intro():
    intro = "Welcome to Wolmorse\nThis program encodes and decodes Morse code."
    print(intro)


def get_input():
    return 'bla', 'bla-bla-bla'


def main():
    while True:
        # your code here
        print_intro()
        mode, message = get_input()
        ui = str.upper(input("Would you like to repeat the program again? Y/N:  "))
        if ui == "Y":
            print(" ")
        elif ui == 'N':
            print("Program is closing...")
            break
        else:
            print("wrong input, try again\n")

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

this is what you should do:
(BTW this is a piece of example code)

```
while True
    name = input('Enter name:')

    print ('Hi '+ name) 
    exit = input('Do you want to exit?(Y/N)')
    
    if exit == 'N' or 'n':
        break
```

(Im not sure if i put the indents correctly )
You can apply this concept into your code.